# import ibm_db is not working in command promt

Tags: python

I have installed ibm_db 2.0.8 in my python 3.6 on Windows 7 machine, using `pip install "ibm-db==2.0.8a"`. From my anaconda 4.6, `import ibm_db` is working.But I need to run this code from command prompt.In my code, before `import ibm_db` I have `import sys` and `import time` In command prompt I'm getting error message `no module named 'ibm_db'` but no error message for `sys` & `time`. Can you suggest me how should I eliminate this error?

Comment: isnt it `import ibm_dbi` not just imb_db

Comment: No,its `import ibm_db`.Please refer this link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSNY3_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html